# how to get the list nodes count in angularfire2?

Tags: list, count, angularfire2

having a list in firebase,

```
List
  key1
    item
  key2
    item
  key3
    item
```

I need to get the list key count, which is in the above case = 3 for this list,

I tried the counter property but get nothing

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The most basic Angular 2 way would be to just iterate over the keys and to increment a counter as you do it.

```js
this.af.database.list(`list`)
.subscribe(keys => {
    keys.forEach(key => this.counter = this.counter + 1)
})
```

A valid objection to this method is that in iterating over all these keys gets you all their children's data. Firebase's [shallow query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-param-shallow) uri parameter allows you to iterate over the keys without loading the data from their children. To do this in Angular 2 you'll have to use the Http module. Here's a rough approximation of that.

```js
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

constructor(private af: AngularFire, private http: Http) { }

countKeys() {
    this.http.get('https://your-database.firebaseio.com/keys.json?shallow=true')
    .subscribe(response => {
        Object.keys(response.json()).forEach(key => this.counter = this.counter + 1))
    }
}
```